# Implementing OpenMP tasks in Fortran?

Tags: parallel-processing, crash, fortran, runtime-error, openmp

I'm new to OpenMP and I'm trying to parallelize an already existing serial code. The code has about 40000 lines, so I can't really post it here.

I'm trying to implement the following code (in C) in Fortran:

```
 my_pointer = listhead;
 #pragma omp parallel
 {
      #pragma omp single nowait
      {
      while(my_pointer) {
      #pragma omp task firstprivate(my_pointer)
      {
      (void) do_independent_work (my_pointer);
      }
 my_pointer = my_pointer->next ;
 }
 } // End of single - no implied barrier (nowait)
 } // End of parallel region - implied barrier
```

In my code:

- my_pointer = zi ;
- listhead = z%first ;
- zi%kc(zi%np) is an array of  of size zi%np ;
- do_independent_work(my_pointer) = ALLOCATE(zi%kc(zi%np)) and initializes the vector to 0 ;

My code is the following:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL
        !$OMP SINGLE 
            DO WHILE(ASSOCIATED(zi))
                IF (zi%compt) THEN
                    !$OMP TASK
                         ALLOCATE(zi%kc(zi%np), STAT = AllocateStatus )
                         IF (AllocateStatus /= 0) STOP "*** zi%kc Allocate failed ***"
                         FORALL(i=1:zi%np)
                         zi%kc(i) = 0.0_SDP
                         END FORALL 
                     !$OMP END TASK
                ENDIF
                zi => zi%next
            ENDDO
        !$OMP END SINGLE NOWAIT
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

The problem is: the serial version of this code runs without any problem, while the parallel version I implemented crashes for some reason.

I'm I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Also, if I put `firstprivate(zi)` next to `!$OMP TASK` I get

> Error 1    error #7266: A F90 pointer is not permitted in an OpenMP*
> FIRSTPRIVATE, LASTPRIVATE or REDUCTION clause.

I'm using Parallel Studio XE 2011 with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Not that it is important, but instead of `FORALL(i=1:zi%np)
                         zi%kc(i) = 0.0_SDP
                         END FORALL ` you can do just `zi%kc = 0`.

Comment: You are right, I'll change it. I'm still annalising the code I've been given.

Answer (score 0):

Fortran pointers were allowed in OpenMP 3.1, you should update your compiler (2011 is old).

Comment: Ok, I'll see to that. Do you recommend any particular version?